# Trouble installing python 3.6.1

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble while installing python 3.6.1, it shows an error like this,please help 
[0*80240017-unspecified error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL9O5.png)

Comment: Please add the error logs in question so that other users can understand the exact error for trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

This error has to do with having to install the C runtime for Windows for Python to work.

Run this first and then reinstall:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows